# My 05 F150 engine knocking

Tags: engine, ford, oil, f-150

Drove it - reached destination and started knocking - NO oil on dipstick. Put in 5 quarts of oil - ran fine until reached next destination - started knocking again - oil was present this time - drove one more time and again started knocking at destination and oil present on dipstick. Knocking does not sound while driving - just when slowing down. No warning lights came on at all. No sign of leaks or burnt oil on tail pipe - any idea what needs fixing?

Comment: Just to be clear you are saying you can only tell there is a knock while the truck is at idle

Comment: When was the last time you had changed the oil?

Comment: Wondering if there is insufficient pressure at idle.  Might be due to bearing damage from running it so low.  If you start it up in the driveway and rev the engine, does the knocking go away at a certain RPM?  I would change the oil ASAP in case there is any metal floating around in the oil.

Comment: Yes - can only hear the knocking while idling.

Comment: It is overdue for oil change